# APC for PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php, wamp, apc

I got WAMP 2.1 running on XP (X86/32 bit) with
Apache Version :
    2.2.17
PHP Version :
    5.3.3
MySQL Version :
    5.5.8

i need apc.
can anyone give any link ?
i tried from pecl.net but all failed saying error MISMATCHED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some PHP extensions compiled for Windows on **[pierre's page](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/)**

A couple of notes, though :

- Those are for the last version of PHP 5.3
- Which is compiled with VC 9, and not VC 6 anymore -- which means you might have to update both Apache and PHP

  - About that, see the note at the bottom of the news of the last release, on http://windows.php.net/

Comment: a direct link will be appreciated though :)

Answer (score 0):

i think APC for PHP compiled on VC 6 can be found here http://dev.freshsite.pl/download.html
but PHP says we should use PHP compiled on VC 6 for better performance and ...